# RESTful OAuth2 and reactjs

Tags: spring, rest, reactjs, spring-data-rest, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring security + oauth2 + restful framework. In addition, the client is reactjs.

But I confused about how to protected client_id,client_secret,username and password.

What I have been got is mixing server and client code, the client posts request to authorization server and gets login page from authorization client. Then, the resource owner inputs password and username. After that, the authorization client will posts client_id,client_secret,username and password to the authorization server and gets access_token to the authorization client. At last the authorization client will return access_token to the browser client that can access resource server.

What I said is right? Can anybody helps me. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// At last the authorization client will return access_token to the browser client.

You can't return access_token from client.  access_token should generate from server and store in client_side application using local storage or cookies.

Comment: I know, I return access_token to browser client and the browser client will store access_token in local storage. And then, the browser client can access resource server by using access_token from local storage.